# WP7 how to make endless listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I see the default Calendar app in Windows Phone 7 has a **Day** tab. In that tab is a `ListBox` that can be scrolled endlessly, and very smoothly.

I'm thinking of changing its binding source, but don't know how to do.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Try dynamic load/unload to onscreen/offscreen list

Comment: hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973180/listbox-items-dynamic-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try binding to a custom IEnumerator. A simple way to do that is to make a method returning a IEnumerable, then use the `yield return` statement to return elements:

```cs
public IEnumerable<int> GetDataSource()
{
    int i = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        yield return i++;
    }
}
```

Then assign it to your listbox:

```cs
this.ListBox.ItemsSource = this.GetDataSource();
```

Just make sure that data virtualization is enabled on the listbox, so items can be loaded on the fly (if the listbox tries to load the whole infinite datasource at once, it obviously won't work)

Comment: you mean UI virtualization or data virtualization ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by UI virtualization. Let's just say that you need to use a `VirtualizingStackPanel`